# Can I mention the official Dungeons and Dragons campaign names on youtube?

Tags: copyright, youtube

We want to start a YouTube channel playing Dungeons and Dragons. Some of our DM's run official campaigns while other's homebrew. I know I can't use pictures and can use the SRD but can I use other titles?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.**

Wizards of the Coast, publisher of the Dungeons & Dragons RPG and associated media, has a [Fan Content Policy](https://company.wizards.com/fancontentpolicy) that covers the situation you describe. In short, the policy allows you to use Wizards' content to create your own works (including video streams of games) and share them with others, provided:

1. You don't charge others for the works you create;
2. You make it clear that your own work is unofficial and not a Wizards of the Coast product;
3. You don't violate any other copyrights or trademarks;
4. You don't use any of Wizards of the Coast's trademarked images, or copyrighted video or music; or incorporate Wizards IP into another game; or remove Wizards legal notices (such as copyright marks) when quoting from Wizards texts;
5. Your content is not offensive or inappropriate in a way that Wizards considers damaging to their brand;
6. If supported by sponsorship: you don't accept sponsorship from one of Wizards' competitors, don't associate the sponsor with Wizards, make it clear that the sponsor is only a sponsor, and keep sponsorship mentions to a reasonable length;
7. You don't otherwise violate the law.

You and your friends should read the Fan Content Policy in detail to make sure you're able to comply with it. I would note that the policy explicitly says that you *can* make money from your fan content -- you just can't directly charge people for it. So ad-supported video streams, sponsorships, and voluntary donations (such as Patreon or Ko-Fi) would be fine.

I would also note that while this is the policy of Wizards of the Coast now, they do still retain copyright on all the content they publish, and they may change their minds and retract the policy. In practice, they probably won't, because fans making and sharing content is very good for their brand -- but they could.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll read the fan content policy and make sure we're well versed on the matter. Again thank you for taking the time to answer